# Using Javascript to open a local MS Access file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to build a web application to replace the functionality of an older desktop economics program. That program is essentially a calculation engine built on top of a Microsoft access database. The inputs and results are all stored on a series of tables. To offer compatibility to the legacy users, I want to have the ability for users to connect to their older, local access databases and upload them into the web app.

The approach I was contemplating was to have a page that allowed the user to select the database they wanted from their local machine and then have the schema and the data for each table sent to the web application. I don't really want to upload the whole file -- I just want to extract the relevant data.

I have done some research and I have looked into the HTML File API. One shortcoming is that the API does not expose the file path of a selected file so there does not seem to be a way to pass that to the connection string necessary to connect to the database using ODBC or ADO.

In summary my basic question is: How can I get the contents of a user's local database into a web application only using the browser?

Comment: I think the only way you can do it is by using ajax. For security reasons you can't read files content unless you upload it. You can try read the content of the file in backend and send back the file content with ajax..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to upload the whole file to the server first. You can do your manipulations on the server to save only the relevant part and delete the rest... For security reasons Javascript is not able to read file's content from the local user's machine.

A suggestion - you can upload the file to server, read and print the relevant data as JSON or XML format, then delete the file and use all the data in your ajax response on the client's browser.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered this was helpful.